# Symfony 2.8 - unrecognized option "default_mapping" under sylius_translation

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

After upgrade of my project from symfony 2.3 to symfony 2.8 I get the following error

```
Unrecognized option "default_mapping" under "sylius_translation"
```

My config.yml file is

```
sylius_translation:
    default_mapping:
        translatable:
            field: translations
            currentLocale: currentLocale
            fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale
        translation:
            field: translatable
            locale: locale
```

Can someone provide me insight ?

Comment: have you activated the bundle in `AppKernel.php` ?

Comment: Yes it is activated. It used to work fine in my previous symfony version 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
sylius.translation.default.mapping:
    translatable:
        ...
    translation:
        ...
```